# How to determine the point at which a doubly linked list becomes a better solution than a simple linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

It's my understanding that doubly linked lists use more memory but less CPU and usually provide better algorithm complexity compared to simple linked lists.

What I would like to know is when a simple linked list offers better overall results compared to a doubly linked list. Is there a clear point/situation after which using one instead of the other is unarguably the best solution? (Like after x elements on a regular PC)

My specific problem:

I'm implementing a linked list structure for general use and am thinking whether or not a link back should be included as it would greatly decrease complexity for element removal.

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**

**At what size does element removal become too expensive on a simple linked list?**

Comment: does it half the time required if we simultaneously travese the list wth next and previous pointers?

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy You mean search time? No, not on a "random" search.  You must still visit n/2 list entries on average, and there's no cost difference between "follow a right link" vs. "follow a left link".

Comment: I don't see how you can answer the updated question without knowing how often you insert to the list.  That's where the run-time cost of a doubly-linked list is incurred.  You also need to know how often forward links are followed without adding or deleting.  To efficiently remove a list entry from a singly-linked list, you need to maintain a "previous" pointer during traversal.  That's effectively one local variable assignment per traversal step.  When does this become "too expensive"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing a data structure is about weighing costs vs benefits, usually work vs upkeep.

A singly linked list offers easy traversal and easy front insertion. Easy tail insertion can be had at the cost of tracking the last node. That cost means whenever you add/remove a node you have to do an additional check (is this the tail?) and a possible update of the list structure.

A doubly linked list adds a lot more maintenance overhead. Every node now has to store two pointers and those have to be managed and maintained.

If you never need to walk backwards in your list, then a singly linked list is ideal, but not being able to walk backwards means that removal is more expensive.

So you need to start by determining which usage pattern you're going to have. If you are building a one-use list, then a singly linked list may be ideal. If you are building a dynamic list with a high rate of removals, then a doubly linked list will be better suited.

Determining specific costs of operations your data structure offers is the topic of things like '[Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)'.

Answer (score 1):

> What I would like to know is when a simple linked list offers better
>   overall results compared to a doubly linked list.

When you don't have to go backwards.

If you're doing a one way linear search, there's no incentive to traverse the list the other direction, and you wouldn't need those pointers.

> UPDATE:
>
> At what size does element removal become too expensive on a simple
>   linked list?

This problem doesn't have anything to with whether a list is singly or doubly linked. if you have to delete something in a list, you need to look for it, which is time complexity `O(n)`. Having an extra pointer to the previous node doesn't help here.

Comment: What about element removal? Won't it become too expensive at a certain size?

Comment: @Douglas Nope, not unless you're deleting things in a non-linear order. You would just need to keep track of a single extra pointer as you walk the list looking for things to delete.

Comment: sorry for not being totally clear. I'll traverse the list, start threads from some elements and then delete these elements after the threads finish. So I'll have a copy of the node address, but to delete it the function will have to go through the list until the element is found `O(n)` in order to update the link to it. In a doubly linked list it won't have to go through the list `O(1)`, just follow the pointer to the node that comes before. What I want to find out is the cost comparison between maintaining an extra pointer per node and iterating through the list to delete an element.

Answer (score 0):

Linked List is a data structure which can be used to implement a stack or a queue, most of the times.  Generally speaking if you are implementing a stack insertion and deletion happen at a single end. if a Q is used usually we delete at one end and add at other end. As you can see both these abstract ds don't need double list and operations add and delete don't depend on number of items. 
As mentioned above by Kepani, the only case where you would be worried about the number of elements in list is when you delete in a fashion not described by a stack / Q interface ( a non-linear approach). which would be when the elements are ordered (it can be otherwise of course) and order needs to be maintained. 
Using a double list is definitely hard on memory requirement as each node needs to maintain an "extra" pointer, unless you are trying to do maintain a store where you refer to past values as well. Dlist will be handy here (Eg: a cli command line interpreter.)
A single list is hard on time as traversals required to reach the previous value of the current node will depend on the number of elements in the list.